# Apache James queue falls behind

Tags: email-server, james

For some reason often I experience queue release issue when delivered message is always one behind actually sent. James is set to send incoming messages to the gateway (Postfix).

RemoteDelivery class has that:

```
        // Set it to try to deliver (in a separate thread) immediately
        // (triggered by storage)
```

What exactly is "storage" and where is configured?

I have set a mailet which sends matched messages (based on recipient domain) to the gateway (specified in the mailetcontainer).
That works fine till some point when it getting "stuck" to be delivered to the gateway. In the James logs it shows as `Successfully spooled mail` from the sender and then it shows as

```
[TID=83] INFO  11:04:54,858 | james.smtpserver | Id='1510412390' User='' Successfully spooled mail Mail1581005094857-978ba32f-74e6-4ca1-b903-7994637a9873 from <address@remote> on <remote sender IP> for [<address@local>]
...
[TID=734] INFO  11:04:55,290 | james.mailetcontext | Remotely delivering mail Mail1581005094857-978ba32f-74e6-4ca1-b903-7994637a9873
[TID=34] INFO  11:04:55,290 | james.mailetcontext | Remote delivery thread (0) will process mail Mail1581005072858-90055113-03cf-4bc0-84d7-d47d176feef2
[TID=34] INFO  11:04:55,290 | james.mailetcontext | Attempting to deliver Mail1581005072858-90055113-03cf-4bc0-84d7-d47d176feef2
[TID=734] INFO  11:04:55,312 | james.mailetcontext | Adding SMTP gateway: <gateway address>
[TID=734] INFO  11:04:55,312 | james.mailetcontext | Sending mail to [<address@local>] via [<gateway address>]
[TID=34] INFO  11:04:55,312 | james.mailetcontext | Adding SMTP gateway: <gateway adrdress>
[TID=34] INFO  11:04:55,312 | james.mailetcontext | Attempting delivery of Mail1581005072858-90055113-03cf-4bc0-84d7-d47d176feef2 to host <gateway adrdress> at <gateway adrdress> from <address@remote> for addresses [<address@local>]]
```

but I don't see that Mail was sent successful to the gateway.

To get it "unstuck" I need to have another incoming message to be send to the James which will hit the same mailet to push previous message to be spooled which got stuck before. Then in the James logs it will appear as

```
[TID=35] INFO  11:22:14,443 | james.mailetcontext | Mail (Mail1581005094857-978ba32f-74e6-4ca1-b903-7994637a9873) sent successfully to <gateway adrdress> at <gateway adrdress> from <address@remote> for [[<address@local>]]
```

All looks like if the relay host changes, the related queue can begin to behave differently, acting like a paper towel tube with ping pong balls pushed into one end.  Only when enough balls have been pushed into get one out the other end.Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It came up that ActiveMQ ver 5.4.2 has a problem. Upgraded to 5.5.1 and queue problem went away.